# Grails domain validation does not work

Tags: hibernate, validation, grails, grails-orm

I am using Grails 2.5.4 and it seems the validation based on constraints defined in domain object does not work.  Given:

```
class Pet {

    String name

    static constraints = {
        name(nullable: false, blank: false)
    }
}
```

When I test with code like the following:

```
    Pet p = new Pet()
    if(!p.save()) {
        p.errors.each {
            println it
        }
    }
```

I expect to see the validation output on the console.  Instead, I receive runtime exception on save():

```
Class
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException
Message
Column 'name' cannot be null
```

This is not the behavior I would expect.  save() is not supposed to make the MySQL insertion call when the validation does not pass.  Does anyone know what the problem is?

I also tested with the following:

```
    Pet e = new Pet()
    e.validate()
    println e.hasErrors()
```

And I get the output false, which is incorrect.

The insertion works fine when I give pet a name.  So the setup seems okay.  Just the validation does not seem to work.

Comment: If you can provide a sample app which demonstrates that behavior, it would be trivial to identify what is going wrong.

Comment: By default, properties are not null and blank strings are converted to null by databinding, so the constraint `name(nullable: false, blank: false)` is largely redundant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turns out to be having hibernate plugin dependency of version 5.0.4

It seems that version does not recognize grails 2.x domain classes.

I upgraded to 5.0.8 and the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

That does not make sense to me.  I would look for a typo in the word `constraints`.

The project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/validationstuff contains the following domain class:

```
// grails-app/domain/demp/Pet.groovy
package demo

class Pet {
    String name

    static constraints = {
        name(nullable: false, blank: false)
    }
}
```

The following controller:

```
// grails-app/controllers/demo/DemoController.groovy
package demo

class DemoController {

    def index() {
        def p = new Pet()
        p.validate()
        def hasErrors = p.hasErrors()

        render "Has Errors? $hasErrors"
    }
}
```

And the following tests:

```
// test/unit/demo/DemoControllerSpec.groovy
package demo

import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification

@TestFor(DemoController)
@Mock(Pet)
class DemoControllerSpec extends Specification {

    void "test validation"() {
        when:
        controller.index()

        then:
        response.text == 'Has Errors? true'
    }
}

// test/unit/demo/PetSpec.groovy
package demo

import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification

@TestFor(Pet)
class PetSpec extends Specification {

    void "test constraints"() {
        expect:
        !new Pet().validate()
    }
}
```

The app contains the following BootStrap:

```
// grails-app/conf/BootStrap.groovy
class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->
        def pet = new demo.Pet()
        pet.validate()

        println "Has Errors? ${pet.hasErrors()}"
    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

At application startup:

```
Has Errors? true
```